# Run unittest in a python module in PyCharm/IntelliJ IDEA12?

Tags: python, unit-testing, intellij-idea, pycharm

In `testsuite/__init__.py`, I write this:

```
import unittest
def suite():
    from my_module.testsuite import (
    shell_command,
    shell_command_on_jinja,
    workflow
    )
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(shell_command.suite())
    suite.addTest(shell_command_on_jinja.suite())
    suite.addTest(workflow.suite())

    return suite
```

In terminal, I can execute the test suite like this:

```
python3 -m unittest testsuite.suite
```

However, I don't know how to config the test for Pycharm/InteliJ.  I add a configuration under `Python's test` and set `Test` to `Function`, `Script` to `my_module/testsuite/__init__.py`, and `Function` to `suite`and then run it. But it doesn't work. Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you take a look at this help page? http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/creating-run-debug-configuration-for-tests.html

Comment: @Nebelmann yes, I checked it. But it didn't mention about this

Comment: No such feature now: http://forum.jetbrains.com/thread/PyCharm-1116

Comment: @lhuang please make your comment an answer (so you can get credit for it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that PyCharm doesn't support this now. Please check the following thread.

http://forum.jetbrains.com/thread/PyCharm-1116